# Average Duration DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to get the mean of a variable typed 'duration' in Power BI, creating a measure like in this formula:

```
Medida = AVERAGE(Consolidado[TMA])
```

When I try this it returns a decimal number like '0.003..', but I can't modify this measure to duration/time.

[image]

Can someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DAX is basically summarizing the result. To overcome this issue add the `FORMAT` function at the beginning and format it accordingly as you need.

```
    Measure = FORMAT(AVERAGEA('Table'[Date]), "HH:MM:SS")
```

This should give you the output in the Time Format.

[image: Output]